# How to target all pages after slug in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding `classes` to specific pages based on slug.

To make it more manageable, I've sorted of these pages into an `array` called `darkThemePages`.

However, one of the groups of pages I'm targeting are blog level 2 pages. The main blog sits on `/insights`. However, what I'm trying to target are all pages under this blog (i.e. `/insights/*`).

However, I can't see a way to target all pages under certain slugs and if it's possible to keep it in an array?

### My approach:

```
  var currentPageURL = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '');
  var root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  var className = "theme--dark";
  var darkThemePages = ['/insights/*', '/terms-and-conditions'];

  if (darkThemePages.indexOf(currentPageURL) > -1) {
    root.classList.add(className);
  } else{
    root.classList.remove(className);
  }
```

Comment: How about using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if a regular expression matches the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) of the current URL, and then add/remove the class from the [root element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) accordingly:

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const className = 'theme--dark';
const regexp = /^\/insights\/.+|^\/terms-and-conditions$/;
root.classList[regexp.test(url.pathname) ? 'add' : 'remove'](className);
```

Here are some tests to show examples of what kinds of url pathnames would/wouldn't match the regular expression:

```js
const regexp = /^\/insights\/.+|^\/terms-and-conditions$/;

for (const pathname of [
  '/insights',
  '/insights/',
  '/insights/post1',
  '/insights/post2',
  '/insights/post1/ok',
  '/about',
  '/terms-and-conditions',
  '/terms-and-conditions/',
  '/terms-and-conditions/etc',
  '/terms-and-conditions-and-more',
]) {
  const matched = regexp.test(pathname) ? '✅' : '❌';
  console.log(matched, pathname);
}
```

And here's a page that explains the regular expression, character by character (you can learn more there and modify/experiment as well): https://regexr.com/75plc

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing me this approach. I didn't even consider regex for this use case. Just one query, in your test `/insights/` returns with a tick because it matches the expression. However, I'm only wanting to target pages after this level. `/insights/` should be an `x` To resolve this, I've tried searching how to add a forward slash in regex, but something like this `/^\/insights/\/|` wouldn't work because of the `escape` string expression. How do I go about this?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75037468/how-to-target-all-pages-after-slug-in-javascript/75037560?noredirect=1#comment132423769_75037560) @Freddy You can just append `.+` to the expression to require 1+ characters: I've updated the answer. I've also updated the `regexr.com` link: be sure to check it out because it includes tons of helpful information about understanding and learning how to create/use regular expressions.

Comment: Many thanks! and will do. Missed seeing the link initially, but very handy.